# MQTT 3.1.1 broker QoS=1 ("at least once") message redelivery

Tags: mqtt, mosquitto, hivemq, mqtt-vernemq

I am trying to find out the reality about **MQTT 3.1.1** message re-delivery for messages received by a MQTT subscriber with "at least once" (QoS 1) configuration:

- Do MQTT brokers re-deliver un-acknowledged "QoS 1" messages from subscribers?
- How much time must pass until MQTT broker re-deliver?
- Does the MQTT broker try endlessly to re-deliver an unacknowledged message?
- Are there other ways to trigger a re-delivery?

Assuming that a MQTT *subscriber* does not respond with a `PUBACK` message to a received MQTT message, the MQTT broker needs (at least from my understanding) re-deliver the message which must be received "at least once" until the subscriber sends a `PUBACK` for that message.

To get more concrete on what I am trying to achieve:
Is it a good/valid idea to postpone sending the `PUBACK` until a received message was successfully persisted - effectively enlarging the QoS level until my subscribing application guaranteed that the message was processed.
And whether for e.g. persistence errors (timeouts to the database) no `PUBACK` would be send which would automatically result in a re-delivery of such messages.

Thx & best regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Do MQTT brokers re-deliver un-acknowledged "QoS 1" messages from subscribers?*

From [the spec]:

> When a Client reconnects with CleanSession set to 0, both the Client and Server MUST re-send any unacknowledged PUBLISH Packets (where QoS > 0) and PUBREL Packets using their original Packet Identifiers [MQTT-4.4.0-1]. This is the only circumstance where a Client or Server is REQUIRED to redeliver messages.

So, yes, unacknowledged QOS1 messages will be redelivered but the only time the spec REQUIRES this to happen is when a client reconnects.

While you specificity state you are using MQTT v3.1.1 I believe it is worth noting that [MQTT v5](https://docs.oasis-open.org/mqtt/mqtt/v5.0/os/mqtt-v5.0-os.html#_Toc385349369) expressly prohibits re-delivery other than following a reconnect:

> When a Client reconnects with Clean Start set to 0 and a session is present, both the Client and Server MUST resend any unacknowledged PUBLISH packets (where QoS > 0) and PUBREL packets using their original Packet Identifiers. This is the only circumstance where a Client or Server is REQUIRED to resend messages. Clients and Servers MUST NOT resend messages at any other time

*How much time must pass until MQTT broker re-deliver?*

As per the above automatic retry is not required by the spec. Some brokers may retransmit after a period of time. [emqx](https://docs.emqx.io/en/broker/v4.3/advanced/retransmission.html#basic-configuration) supports this; mosquitto used to have an option but this was removed in version 1.5 with the [change log](https://github.com/eclipse/mosquitto/blob/master/ChangeLog.txt) explaining:.

> Outgoing messages with QoS>1 are no longer retried after a timeout period.
> Messages will be retried when a client reconnects.  This change in behaviour
> can be justified by considering when the timeout may have occurred.
>
> - If a connection is unreliable and has dropped, but without one end
>   noticing, the messages will be retried on reconnection. Sending
>   additional PUBLISH or PUBREL would not have changed anything.
> - If a client is overloaded/unable to respond/has a slow connection then
>   sending additional PUBLISH or PUBREL would not help the client catch
>   up. Once the backlog has cleared the client will respond. If it is not
>   able to catch up, sending additional duplicates would not help either

*Does the MQTT broker try endlessly to re-deliver an unacknowledged message?*

The 3.11 spec does not provide any guidance (so, in theory, yes) but many brokers provide some control over this (maximum number of messages queued, max size of queue etc).

*Are there other ways to trigger a re-delivery?*

Yes - disconnect and reconnect.

*Is it a good/valid idea to postpone sending the PUBACK until a received message was successfully persisted*

There was a discussion re this on the [paho-dev group a couple of months ago](https://www.eclipse.org/lists/paho-dev/msg04651.html). Its something that is being considered in the [Go v5 Client](https://github.com/eclipse/paho.golang/issues/53) (currently that client automatically acknowledges messages).

One thing to note is that the MQTT spec does have requirements with regards to the [order acknowledgments are sent](http://docs.oasis-open.org/mqtt/mqtt/v3.1.1/os/mqtt-v3.1.1-os.html#_Toc370160808). Many clients ignore this requirement (and just send the acknowledgments whenever the handler returns) but some (e.g. the [HiveMQ Java client](https://github.com/hivemq/hivemq-mqtt-client/releases/tag/v1.2.0)) queue up ACKs so they can be sent in the correct order.

Comment: Thx for the detailed answer. I guess based on the MQTT spec, one cannot compare the "acknowledgement" of other messaging protocols like AMQP 0.9.1 or AMQP 1.0 with the one from MQTT - MQTT seems to handle the `PUBACK` similar to an TCP packet ACK.