# What happens when a message is published with QoS=1?

Tags: mqtt, aws-iot, mqtt.js

I would like to have a better understanding of the behavior of this library.
Specifically: let's say I have an open connection (over WSS, if this change anything) with an MQTT server.
I publish a message with QoS=1.
My understanding is that mqtt awaits for a PUBACK message. After the ack has been received, the done callback is called and the flow is ended.
What is not clear to me is the low-level stuff: how much "time" do the library awaits for the ack? what happen if the ack doesn't come? the message is resent? the connection is closed/reopened? something else?
Is this behavior tunable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prior to answering your specific question I feel its worth outlining what the protocol requires (I'll highlight the key term). The [MQTT 3.1.11 spec](http://docs.oasis-open.org/mqtt/mqtt/v3.1.1/os/mqtt-v3.1.1-os.html#_Ref383618483) says:

> When a Client reconnects with CleanSession set to 0, both the Client and Server MUST re-send any unacknowledged PUBLISH Packets (where QoS > 0) and PUBREL Packets using their original Packet Identifiers [MQTT-4.4.0-1]. This is **the only circumstance** where a Client or Server **is REQUIRED** to redeliver messages.

The [v5 spec](https://docs.oasis-open.org/mqtt/mqtt/v5.0/os/mqtt-v5.0-os.html#_Toc3901238) tightens this:

> When a Client reconnects with Clean Start set to 0 and a session is present, both the Client and Server MUST resend any unacknowledged PUBLISH packets (where QoS > 0) and PUBREL packets using their original Packet Identifiers. This is the only circumstance where a Client or Server is REQUIRED to resend messages. Clients and Servers **MUST NOT resend** messages at any other time [MQTT-4.4.0-1].

So the only time the spec requires that the publish be resent is when the client reconnects. v3.1.1 does not prohibit resending at other times but I would not recommend doing this (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67594051/11810946) for more info).

Looking specifically at mqtt.js I have scanned through the code and the only resend mechanism I can see is when the connection [is established](https://github.com/mqttjs/MQTT.js/blob/5c04ab498e3ac57b7979d8edb53b4f23050121d1/lib/client.js#L1869) (backed up by [this issue](https://github.com/mqttjs/MQTT.js/issues/47)). So to answer your specific questions:

> how much "time" do the library awaits for the ack?

There is no limit; the [callback is stored](https://github.com/mqttjs/MQTT.js/blob/5c04ab498e3ac57b7979d8edb53b4f23050121d1/lib/client.js#L651) and called when the flow completes ([for example](https://github.com/mqttjs/MQTT.js/blob/5c04ab498e3ac57b7979d8edb53b4f23050121d1/lib/client.js#L1615)).

> what happen if the ack doesn't come? the message is resent? the connection is closed/reopened? something else?

Nothing. However in reality the use of TCP/IP means that if a message is not delivered then the connection should drop (and if the broker receives the message, but is unable to process it, then it should really drop the connection).

> Is this behavior tunable?

I guess you could implement a timed resend but this is unlikely to be a good idea (and doing so would breach the v5 spec). A better approach might be to drop the connection if a message is not acknowledged within a set time frame. However there really should be no need to do this.

Comment: Looking at the code I agree that "nothing" is what happen "just after" the missing PUBACK. Now I have another doubt, however: as you said "the connection should drop", but how? should/could the library "force" the drop of the connection? I ask this because I just used a very dumb MITMproxy script between my client and my server, blocking the server PUBACK responses, and... nothing happened from my client for solid 10 minutes...

Comment: "A stream of data sent on a TCP connection is delivered reliably and in order at the destination." ([RFP793](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc793)). As TCP is used to transmit MQTT packets you can safely assume that either the packets will be received in order or subsequent packets will not be received at all. A [half-open](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TCP_half-open) connection may prevent delivery but keepalives should detect that. The spec states that the network must "provide ordered, lossless, bi-directional connections" (so if yours does not then another protocol may be needed).